# Sliding Between Web Pages using jquery/ajax or html5

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, slide

I am trying to understand how to create the effect of clicking on a right arrow and the content of the webpage (Everything except for the footer and header) slides off to the left, and another html page I have written slides in from the right.

From my research on stackoverflow I understand that this is possible with either jquery/ajax or html5, however, all of the resources provided thus far have not been able to explain how to accomplish this task. The web pages I have been lead to for jquery have shown me how to slide between different divs inside a single html page but not between the html pages themselves.

I am looking to replicate the effect of

http://www.kickstarter.com/year/2012#dark_sky

if someone can point me in the right direction of how to accomplish this it would be greatly appreciated.

Thankyou

Comment: please do some effort, show code that not working for you etc..you're asking people for help, show you're putting in the effort on your end too ;)

Answer (score 0):

as you can successfully slide between divs, why not simply embed the html-pages in different `iframe` and switch between those?

Not sure if this solution is appropriate for you, but I would give it a try ;)